# If a triangle $PQR$ is constructed such that All sides are integers ; and , $PQ= 37 , QR= M$ , and $M <37$ , then the possible values of $PR$ :

Tags: inequality, triangles

If a triangle $PQR$ is constructed such that All sides are integers ; and , $PQ= 37  , QR= M$  , and  $M <37$ , then the possible values of $PR$  :

A) $2M-2$

B)$2M-1$

C)$2M$

D)$2M+1$

I tried to apply triangle inequality

$37-M <PR <M+37$
$1 <PR <2M+1$         since Max (m)=$36$

But i can't reject except  $D$  ; what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is confused, but from $PR<M+37$ you can't conclude $PR<2M+1$, you can only say $PR<max(M)+37$

Comment: This should be written as a comment, since it is not really an answer

Comment: I know but I can't comment yet

Comment: And I also think maybe it was the answer he was looking for

Comment: Your response doesn't make sense in that $M$ is just a single (unspecified) value, so $\max(M)$ will not appear in the solution.

Comment: I know $M$ is just a single value, I only wrote that you can conclude $PR<73$ (I wrote $max(M)$ to be clearer) and not $PR<2M+1$. The question he asks is "what should I do?" and I think the answer I gave clarifies where the error in his arguments is. I wonder if you didn't read the question before commenting or I completely misunderstood it. Probably the latter.